# Modify animatingTo in flexslider

Tags: javascript, flexslider

I've got a little application that shows one photo in the middle of the page, some right/left buttons for changing the photo, and a flexslider at the bottom of the page having thumbnails of all available photos. Depending on the width of the browser, 4 to 10 thumbnails are visible at a time.

I want to synchronize the slider with the main photo. I've turned animation off. And when I click on something in the slider, the main photo updates. I've got this working.

But when I change which photo is shown using the right/left arrows, I want to update the slider so that the thumbnail for the main photo is shown, as in, move the slider right or left. I tried just manually changing (increment or decrement) the `slider.animatingTo` value, but that doesn't update the slider on the screen.

I've also tried, by modifying the `jquery.flexslider.js` file, putting one of the `update` methods onto the `slider` object (essentially making it public). But I'm not sure what the right function to call would be.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
  slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("prev"));
```

and

```
  slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next"));
```